# 'fatal: No url found for submodule path' error when trying to init submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

The name of the repository that I am using as a submodule in my current repository is `droid-media-lib`, but the name of the directory into which this submodule is put into is `library` so my .gitmodules looks like this

```
[submodule "droid-media-lib"]
        path = library/
        url = https://github.com/talview/droid-media-lib.git
```

Now when I am trying to clone this project on a different computer, and do

```
git submodule update --init
```

I get this error

```
fatal: No url found for submodule path 'library' in .gitmodules
```

What I've tried so far:

- I've tried changing submodule "droid-media-lib" to submodule "library", still getting same error.
- I've tried renaming the library directory name to droid-media-lib and setting the same value in path as `path = droid-media-lib/"` , but surprisingly the error message stays the same with "library" in it, I don't understand where its reading the "library" string from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Submodule paths may not end in a slash.

```
path=library/
```

is an invalid configuration, instead you can have:

```
path=library
```